# phpのコーディングスタイルについて

Tags: php

先日`$obj->hoge->huga`を`$obj -> hoge -> huga`という風に`->`の両側にスペースをつけているコードを見かけました。

今まで見たことないスタイルだったのですが、みなさんは見たことありますか?
メリットなどがあれば教えて下さい。

私が使ってるエディタではシンタックスハイライトがうまく機能しなかったので、気になり質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2):

ご質問のにお答えすると、アローの両側に空白は見たことがありません。
おそらくその人の癖なのでしょう。
従うも従わずも、場の空気に合わせるといいと思います。

---

### 余談

共通開発、中規模・大規模開発の際にスタイルを統一するのは色々なメリットがあります。
読みやすくなることによってコードを理解していくうえで齟齬が発生しにくくなります。
また、スタイルが崩れたことによって見通しが悪くなったものは、メンテナンスもし難くなります。
何より、何らかのツールによって (例えば複雑度計測ツール等) 継続的にメンテナンスしている場合でも、スタイルから外れることによって計測から弾かれてしまうことも考えられます。(特に自作ツールで運用している企業さんとか)

スタイルの統一というのは、様々な面で利益を生みます。
しかしそのスタイルに慣れるまで見にくく感じたりというデメリットもあります。

1年後の自分にとって為になるコーディングを心がければ、自然とスタイルに気を使うようになると思います。

コーディングスタイルとはズレますが、PHP には [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) という団体が定めた PSR というコーディング規約があります。

日本語訳はインフィニットループさんのブログが比較的有名です。
http://www.infiniteloop.co.jp/blog/2012/10/psrphp/

お役にたてれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

私自身はコーディングスタイル否定派なのですが。見たことも使ったこともあります。
あ。もちろん一般的とは言いがたいのは認めます。
古いコーディングチェッカーであればサポートしているのもありましたが……今どきは無いでしょう。
（今でもサポートしているチェッカーがあれば是非教えてください！）

通常であれば「論理、代入、…、…に該当する演算子の前後にはスペースを」と書くのでしょうが。
「演算子の前後はスペースを入れる」と包括的な表現担っている場合は、アロー演算子も三項演算子やダブルアロー演算子と同じ演算子ですから前後のスペースが必要になります。

コーディングスタイルにメリットなんてありません。
読みやすいか読みにくいかだけですから。そのようなルールが定められているということは、
その現場ではそれが読みやすいという文化でありルールだということです。
（そこまで考えておらず単なる惰性なのかもしれませんが）

Comment: そういえば。 => はダブルアロー演算子ですから。 => の前後にはスペースを認めて、 -> の前後にはスペースを認めないというのも不思議な話ですね。　と感じる人はいるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど。
もう好みや思想の問題ですね。
決まりであればそう書くし、決まりでなければ好きに書けばいいかなと思いました。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: あー。一応自己弁護しておきますが。コーディングスタイル否定派なのは私が「C++ Coding Standards」を昔からずっと読んでいた（感化されている）影響です。  ですので他の方の回答にあるように「計測等に使っている可能性」のように、ルールはルールとして合理的な理由があるはずなのです。（ただ可読性だけってなら。それはスタイルの問題じゃなくて、コーディングそのものの問題ということです）。ルールの背景を知るのは、現場やコミュニティを知るにも良いことです。